# PL/SQL: SQL Statement Ignored & ORA - 00984: Column Not Allowed Here

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am having a few issues with my stored procedure. If you could help me out, that would be great. Thanks!

```
Create or replace procedure final(Minimum in number)

is

Cursor salary_cursor(Minimum_salary number) is
  select first_name || ' ' || last_name employee, department_name, job_title,
  min_salary, salary from employees
  join departments using (department_id)
  join jobs using (job_id)
  where Minimum_salary <= min_salary;

begin
  for x in salary_cursor(Minimum) loop
    insert into finalrept values(n.Employee_name, n.department_name, n.job_title,
    n.min_salary, n.salary);

end loop;

Exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM || ', ' || SQLCODE);

end final;
/
sho err
```

I can't seem to figure out why I am getting these errors! any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `WHEN OTHERS` exception block, it hides the actual error and line number. As a good coding practice, it is considered a bug itself. See [WHEN OTHERS – A bug](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/02/when-others-then-null-a-bug/)

Comment: Juse replace **n.** s to **x.**

Comment: Why this slow row-by-row cursor approach? The whole procedure can be replaced with a single `insert` statement. No PL/SQL required

Answer (score 0):

Few things I can suggest by seeing code that, when you insert , you need to insert like x.column_name not sure why are you using n.column_name , also make sure the column_name matches with your select query. I see employee_name while inserting but its employee in the query

Comment: That was it! I didn't see the difference between the employee_name and the query. Thanks!